# cconfig.obj and cutility.obj error lnk2001. Cannot find any info on those 2 obj files

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator

I keep having an issue when compiling on QTcreator. It is QT4 based on a qt3 code.
I fixed most of the issues I encountered but this one I am stuck on.

```
22:54:57: Running steps for project brickstock... 
22:54:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\4.8.7\bin\qmake.exe" C:\bl\brickstock-1.2.13-src\brickstock.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=release"
22:54:58: The process "C:\Qt\4.8.7\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
22:54:58: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 

    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.7\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:".obj\brickstock.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:release\brickstock.exe @C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\brickstock.exe.1172.47.jom
bricklink.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance

cconfig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExW@24

cconfig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyExW@20

cconfig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__SHGetSpecialFolderPathW@16

cconfig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4

cutility.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShellExecuteW@24

release\brickstock.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

jom: C:\bl\build-brickstock-4_8_7-Release\Makefile.Release [release\brickstock.exe] Error 1120

jom: C:\bl\build-brickstock-4_8_7-Release\Makefile [release] Error 2

22:55:00: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.

Error while building/deploying project brickstock (kit: 4.8.7)

The kit 4.8.7 has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
22:55:00: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

I have the cconfig.h and cutility.h but I cannot find any info on cconfig.obj or cutility.obj.

Comment: Fix it by adding

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding:

#pragma comment(lib, "SHELL32.LIB")

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

In the cconfig.cpp**strong text**